# Why is restrict_xpath neglecting hrefs inside inside <a> tags?

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm scraping a wikipedia page to extract all image urls and here's the code for it.

```
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule

class WikiSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'wiki'
    allowed_domains = ['en.wikipedia.org']
    start_urls = ['https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Katy_Perry']

    rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=('//a[@class="image"]')), 
             callback='parse_item', follow=False),] 

    def parse_item(self, response):
        print(response.url)
```

When I run the spider, it isn't showing any results, but when I change the xpath inside `restrict_xpaths` it prints some random links. I need hrefs in the xpath `'//a[@class="image"]'` but it isn't working, what's the reason ? I know that I could use basic spider instead of `CrawlSpider` and avoid rules altogether. But I wanna know why the xpath I entered didn't work and what kind of xpaths and html tags does `restrict_xpaths` accept ?

Comment: You would pass something like `restrict_xpaths='//td[@colspan="2"]')` where the anchors are inside

Comment: But I passed `<a>` tags as xpaths before and all of them worked. For instance in [reddit.com/r/pics](https://www.reddit.com/r/pics), to grab the `href` inside the next page button I used `//a[@rel="nofollow next"]` and it works, it crawls next pages. I dont understand why the similar xpath `//a[@class="image"]` doesn't work in this example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The links you want are images:

```
$ scrapy shell "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Katy_Perry" -s USER_AGENT='Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.82 Safari/537.36'
2016-08-19 11:17:05 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.1.2 started (bot: scrapybot)
(...)
2016-08-19 11:17:06 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Katy_Perry> (referer: None)
(...)
In [1]: response.xpath('//a[@class="image"]/@href').extract()
Out[1]: 
['/wiki/File:Katy_Perry_DNC_July_2016_(cropped).jpg',
 '/wiki/File:Katy_Perry_performing.jpg',
 '/wiki/File:Katy_Perry%E2%80%93Zenith_Paris.jpg',
 '/wiki/File:PWT_Cropped.jpg',
 '/wiki/File:Alanis_Morissette_5-19-2014.jpg',
 '/wiki/File:Freddie_Mercury_performing_in_New_Haven,_CT,_November_1977.jpg',
 '/wiki/File:Katy_Perry_California_Dreams_Tour_01.jpg',
 '/wiki/File:Katy_Perry_UNICEF_2012.jpg',
 '/wiki/File:Katy_Perry_Hillary_Clinton,_I%27m_With_Her_Concert.jpg',
 '/wiki/File:Wikiquote-logo.svg',
 '/wiki/File:Commons-logo.svg']
```

And by default link extractors filter [a lot of extensions](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/bb3b806467c1a79ad0ff3c8012e9366cc6066f2a/scrapy/linkextractors/__init__.py#L21), including images:

```
In [2]: from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

In [3]: LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=('//a[@class="image"]')).extract_links(response)
Out[3]: []
```

You can [use `deny_extensions=[]`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html#scrapy.linkextractors.lxmlhtml.LxmlLinkExtractor) to not filter anything:

```
In [4]: LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=('//a[@class="image"]'), deny_extensions=[]).extract_links(response)
Out[4]: 
[Link(url='https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Katy_Perry_DNC_July_2016_(cropped).jpg', text='', fragment='', nofollow=False),
 Link(url='https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Katy_Perry_performing.jpg', text='', fragment='', nofollow=False),
 Link(url='https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Katy_Perry%E2%80%93Zenith_Paris.jpg', text='', fragment='', nofollow=False),
 Link(url='https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:PWT_Cropped.jpg', text='', fragment='', nofollow=False),
 Link(url='https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Alanis_Morissette_5-19-2014.jpg', text='', fragment='', nofollow=False),
 Link(url='https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Freddie_Mercury_performing_in_New_Haven,_CT,_November_1977.jpg', text='', fragment='', nofollow=False),
 Link(url='https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Katy_Perry_California_Dreams_Tour_01.jpg', text='', fragment='', nofollow=False),
 Link(url='https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Katy_Perry_UNICEF_2012.jpg', text='', fragment='', nofollow=False),
 Link(url="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Katy_Perry_Hillary_Clinton,_I'm_With_Her_Concert.jpg", text='', fragment='', nofollow=False),
 Link(url='https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Wikiquote-logo.svg', text='', fragment='', nofollow=False),
 Link(url='https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Commons-logo.svg', text='', fragment='', nofollow=False)]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I almost never use debugger and now I know how to use it properly.

Comment: Scrapy shell is not really a debugger but it's one of your best friend in scrapy projects.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, I tried to grab image link from `src` attribute inside `img` tag like this `LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=('//img'),deny_extensions=[]).extract_links(response)`. Then I changed the `attrs` parameter to `src` like this `LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=('//img'),deny_extensions=[],attrs=('src')).extract_links(response)`, both of them return empty list. I know it's all unnecessary, but doesn't `restrict_xpath` accept any tag or did I do anything wrong ?